# Symfony - One to Many with one active

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many, symfony6

I would like to ask what is the best approach for this in Symfony.

E.g. there is one entity ***User*** with the One to Many relation to another entity ***Address***.
Let's say the ***User*** can have multiple delivery addresses in the e-shop, while exactly one is active as preset, with the possibility to choose other stored addresses. Or "*the active address*" is seen as the billing address.

Without Symfony, I could use e.g. stored procedure or the view with two possibilities.
Having another column/property of the ***User***, holding ID of "*the active address*" record, or having another (e.g. boolean) column/property of the ***Address*** saying if the record is the active one. Then the view or stored procedure can easily return a single record containing the ***User*** data including "*the active address*". It would depend on other requirements, e.g. if it's needed to get the list of all active addresses, without the need of joining a ***User*** table/entity.

How this could be achieved in the Symphony the clean way according to best practices?

And "a less urgent", related question, by the way. Does Symfony / Doctrine support some preferred way to work with stored procedures? E.g. when complete business logic, including validations, access rights, etc. is implemented at the DB level and multiple clients (e.g. desktop app, web app, mobile app, ...) are using stored procedures instead of reimplementing business logic in each of them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, using an active flag on the address is probably the most common approach.  I did want to point out that a join will always be used anytime you are dealing with user/address combos.  Doctrine often hides the join from the developer but it is always there.  Stored procedures don't tend to be used all that much at least in my experience.  It depends quite a bit on what happens when you validations/access fails.  Doctrine does not do well with exceptions.

Comment: [PHP Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/) might be a better place for open ended stored procedure opinion oriented questions.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! "Best Practice" questions are frowned upon here. Usually you want to present some code that doesn't work and ask for help.

There are probably several solutions to your issue. If I were implementing a solution, I would probably add a boolean `active` property to the `Address` entity. Then in the `User` entity I would add a method like

```php
public function getActiveAddress(): Address
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("active", true))
    ;

    return $this->getAddresses()->matching($criteria);
}
```